# Check the layer that the CCSprite was added to

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

**cocos2d**: Please show me how to display the console CCLayer, to which was added CCSprite?

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bird.png"];
sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2-100, winSize.height/2);
[super addChild:sprite];
NSLog();
```

I now bring to the console name of the layer to which was added a sprite?

Comment: First you should never use `[super addChild:sprite]` it's suppose to be `[self addChild:sprite]`

Comment: I use [self addChild:sprite], but I just need to add another layer to the sprite and tried super

Comment: You mean add another visible sprite?

Comment: I have:
  @ interface HudLayer: CCLayer
@ end
@ interface HelloWorldLayer: CCLayer
@ end
Now I need a method to add HudLayer sprite, which will be located on a layer HelloWorldLayer
Sorry for my English, I'm Russian)

Comment: Use [self addChild:sprite] on the layer of the class you wish to add the sprite to. Example: if you wanted to add a sprite to the HUDLayer, use [self addChild:sprite] in the HUDLayer.m Class. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: super is not parent ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you wanted to [super addChild], did you mean [self.parent addChild:sprite] ? To answer your question

```
NSLog(@"SPrite's parent is %@",sprite.parent];
```

that will give you by default the 'description' property for any CCNode. I find it un-informative, by and large. But that will log on the console the 'object' of which sprite is a child.